# Firefly Wallet Migration

Tags: wallet, firefly, migration

Hi IOTA professionals,

I installed firefly and migrated a very old wallet using my 81er key. It seems as if its doing something, but I have issues sending more coins from binanvcer, it looks like the address is in a different/strange format:

[image]

Comment: ok I think it was because I was logged into a node in the dev-net. Please ignore

Comment: Yes, `atoi1...` are devnet addresses.